# Best Practices for Difference-in-Difference Analysis of Quasi-Experimental Repeated Cross-Sectional (Cat.) Data Different Samples per Neighborhood

Tags: r, categorical-data, difference-in-difference, lm, cross-section

I'm working with repeated cross-sectional data where each measure comes from a different sample of respondents per neighborhood. My study aims to evaluate the impact of varying police patrol levels (more patrols, fewer patrols, and normal levels) on neighborhood livability scores, using pre- and post-intervention measures.

I'm considering different approaches to analyze my data and have a few questions:

1. Given the nature of my data (different samples per neighborhood at
   each time point), is it appropriate to analyze the results at the
   individual respondent level as I am currently doing, or should I
   aggregate the data to the neighborhood level and use means or
   medians? Alternatively, is incorporating some form of hierarchical
   structure in my Difference-in-Difference (DiD) model advisable?
2. In my current DiD analysis, I'm comparing three groups: `treatment+` (more police patrol), `treatment-` (less police patrol), and `control` (normal levels of police patrol). I'm unsure if I should include all three groups in the same DiD model or analyze the treatment+ and treatment- groups in isolation. And is my overall approach to DiD analysis correct, and how should I interpret these findings?
3. Lastly, I'm looking for suggestions on more suitable ways to
   visualize pre- and post-intervention data for the three groups. My
   current approach involves boxplots, but I'm open to other
   recommendations.

```
Call:
lm(formula = LW_CFleef_a ~ DiD, data = combined_data_test)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9991 -0.9987  0.0009  1.0009  3.0009 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         6.99915    0.02126 329.253   <2e-16 ***
DiDtreatment+.pre  -0.88150    0.09669  -9.117   <2e-16 ***
DiDtreatment-.pre  -0.98388    0.09238 -10.650   <2e-16 ***
DiDcontrol.post     0.99957    0.03006  33.249   <2e-16 ***
DiDtreatment+.post  1.10765    0.10359  10.692   <2e-16 ***
DiDtreatment-.post  0.06888    0.08749   0.787    0.431    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.029 on 5180 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2394,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2387 
F-statistic: 326.1 on 5 and 5180 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

[image]

For context, here's a snippet of how I'm preparing my data and conducting the analysis (including simulated data for a workable example):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Simulated data generation
n_vn <- 250 
n_vmaa <-2500
buurten <- c("AA01", "AA02", "AA03", "AA04", "AA05", "AA06")  # Example neighborhood codes
wijken <- c( "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AJ", "AK", "BB", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", "EE", "EF", "EG", "EH", "EJ", "EK", "EL", "EM", "EN", "EP", "EQ", "ER", "ES", "ET", "EU", "EV", "FM", "FP", "KA", "KB", "KC", "KD", "KE", "KF", "KG", "KH", "KJ", "KK", "KL", "KM", "KN", "KP", "MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MM", "MN", "MP", "MQ", "NA", "NB", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NF", "NG", "NH", "NJ", "NK", "NL", "NM", "NN", "NP", "NQ")  

simulated_data_VN_pre <- tibble::tibble(
  LW_CFleef_a = pmin(pmax(round(rnorm(n_vn, mean = 6, sd = 1)), 1), 10),
  AREA = factor(sample(buurten, n_vn, replace = TRUE)),
  GROUP = factor(if_else(AREA %in% c("AA04", "AA05", "AA06"), "treatment+", "treatment-")),
  SURVEY = factor(sample(1, n_vn, replace = TRUE), labels = c("VN")),
  TIME = factor(sample(1, n_vn, replace = TRUE), labels = c("pre"))
)

simulated_data_VN_post <- tibble::tibble(
  LW_CFleef_a = pmin(pmax(round(rnorm(n_vn, mean = 8, sd = 1)), 1), 10),
  AREA = factor(sample(buurten, n_vn, replace = TRUE)),
  GROUP = factor(if_else(AREA %in% c("AA04", "AA05", "AA06"), "treatment+", "treatment-")),
  SURVEY = factor(sample(1, n_vn, replace = TRUE), labels = c("VN")),
  TIME = factor(sample(1, n_vn, replace = TRUE), labels = c("post"))
) %>% 
  mutate(LW_CFleef_a = case_when(GROUP == "treatment-" ~ LW_CFleef_a - 1, TRUE ~ LW_CFleef_a))

# VMAA pre
simulated_data_VMAA_pre <- tibble::tibble(
  LW_CFleef_a = pmin(pmax(round(rnorm(n_vmaa, mean = 7, sd = 1)), 1), 10),
  AREA = factor(sample(wijken, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE)),
  GROUP = factor(sample(1, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE), labels = c("control")),
  SURVEY = factor(sample(1, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE), labels = c("VMAA")),
  TIME = factor(sample(1, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE), labels = c("pre"))
)

# VMAA post
simulated_data_VMAA_post <- tibble::tibble(
  LW_CFleef_a = pmin(pmax(round(rnorm(n_vmaa, mean = 8, sd = 1)), 1), 10),
  AREA = factor(sample(wijken, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE)),
  GROUP = factor(sample(1, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE), labels = c("control")),
  SURVEY = factor(sample(1, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE), labels = c("VMAA")),
  TIME = factor(sample(1, n_vmaa, replace = TRUE), labels = c("post"))
)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Combineer de dataframes
combined_data <- bind_rows(simulated_data_VMAA_pre, 
                           simulated_data_VMAA_post, 
                           simulated_data_VN_pre,
                           simulated_data_VN_post)

combined_data_test$LW_CFleef_a <- as.integer(combined_data_test$LW_CFleef_a)
combined_data_test$GROUP <- factor(combined_data_test$GROUP, levels = c("treatment+", "treatment-", "control"))
combined_data_test$SURVEY <- factor(combined_data_test$SURVEY, levels = c("VN", "VMAA"))
combined_data_test$TIME <- factor(combined_data_test$TIME, levels = c("pre", "post"))


combined_data_test$DiD <- interaction(combined_data_test$GROUP, combined_data_test$TIME)
combined_data_test$DiD <- factor(combined_data_test$DiD, levels = c("control.pre", "treatment+.pre", "treatment-.pre", "control.post", "treatment+.post", "treatment-.post"))

did_model <- lm(LW_CFleef_a ~ DiD, data = combined_data_test)
summary(did_model)

combined_data_test$predicted <- predict(did_model, newdata = combined_data_test)

# Create a violin plot
ggplot(combined_data_test, aes(x = TIME, y = LW_CFleef_a, fill = GROUP)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("control" = "grey", "treatment+" = "blue", "treatment-" = "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 10, by = 1), limits = c(3, 10)) + # Set y-axis breaks and limits
  facet_wrap(~GROUP, scales = "free_y") + # Facet by group to separate the violins by group
  labs(
    x = "Time",
    y = "Neighborhood Livability Score",
    fill = "Group",
    title = "Neighborhood Livability Score Distribution by Group Over Time"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

I appreciate any guidance or insights you can provide on these questions.

Comment: A follow-up regarding your second question. Are these three discrete treatments, such as high, normal, and low patrol intensity? Also, what is less patrol mean in this setting? Is it, say, a reactive police response in those areas, or is it something like a 50 percent reduction in staffing? Since I do research in this area, I am genuinely curious.